# Two sensors to one ADC pin

Tags: switches, analog, adc, mbed

I'm working on a project using the MBED 1768, where I would like to connect two different externally powered sensors to one ADC pin on the microcontroller. Since they are externally powered, I need a way to switch between the input signals in such a way that only one sensor is connected to the input at a time, and this switching has to somehow be triggered electrically by the microcontroller. How would I go about doing this, preferably in a cheap way?

Comment: I recommend reading basic information about multiplexing analog signals. This is, what you are going to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a 2:1 analogue multiplexer like the [74LVC1G3157](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjpsLH1upjZAhVKKlAKHXMwCb0QFgiVAjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets.nexperia.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata-sheet%2F74LVC1G3157.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1m2BOihuAjJObBzA2W-RMn) or many others that are readily available. The devil is in the detail and you need to work out what specific multiplexer suits your needs in terms of voltage levels coming in and what power supplies you have available.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an analog switch. 
There are thousands on the market. 
For example TI: 
http://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/products.html

Search for your exact needs